# How to use Knockout to sync links between Typescript instances

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have a TypeScript class links to another class.  The other class has a corresponding links back to the first class.

How would I use Knockout.js to set the reverse link automatically?  The following is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class Address {
    constructor() {
        this.person = ko.observable<Person>();
    }
    person: KnockoutObservable<Person>;
}

class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.address = ko.observable<Address>();
    }
    address: KnockoutObservable<Address>;
}

var p = new Person();
var a = new Address();

a.person(p); // Which should make: p.a() == a;
a.person(null); // Which should make: p.a() == null;
```

---

Update: here's my TS translation for Sjoerd's JS answer below:

```
interface KnockoutExtenders {
    logChange(target: any, option: string): KnockoutObservable<any>;
    syncLink(target: any, other: PropDef): KnockoutObservable<any>;
}

interface PropDef {
    self: any;
    property: string;
}

ko.extenders.bind = function (target, option) {
    target.subscribe(function (newValue) {

        var oldValue = target['oldValue'];
        target['oldValue'] = newValue;
        if (typeof oldValue != 'undefined' && oldValue != null && newValue != oldValue) {
            oldValue[option.property](undefined);
        }

        if (typeof newValue != 'undefined' && newValue != null && newValue != oldValue) {
            newValue[option.property](target);
        }
    });

    return target;
};

class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.address = ko.observable<Address>()
            .extend({ bind: { self: this, property: "person" } });
    }
    address: KnockoutObservable<Address>;
}

class Address {
    constructor() {
        this.person = ko.observable<Person>()
            .extend({ bind: { self: this, property: "address" } });
    }
    person: KnockoutObservable<Person>;
}
```

Comment: If this isn't just a made-up example, I would, despite the interesting question, say that it's a weird design that `Address` has a `person` member.

Comment: The model is not the real domain, just an example to show the goal.

Comment: Are the comments in the last two lines of code what you'd like to see?  Or is that what you're actually seeing?

Comment: They're what I want to see.  Have updated the question to indicate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a possible solution for your problem. It is a simple extender which binds two observables together.

http://jsfiddle.net/vBrw2/4/

```
ko.extenders['bind'] = function (target, option) {
    var prop = option.property;
    var self = option.self;

    target.subscribe(function (newValue) {

        var oldValue = target['oldValue'];
        target['oldValue'] = newValue;
        if (typeof oldValue != 'undefined' && oldValue != null && newValue != oldValue) {
            oldValue[option.property](undefined);
        }

        if (typeof newValue != 'undefined' && newValue != null && newValue != oldValue) {
            newValue[option.property](option.self);
        }
    });

    return target;
};

var Address = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.street = "";
    self.person = ko.observable().extend({
        bind: {
            self: self,
            property: "address"
        }
    });

    return self;
};

var Person = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = "";
    self.address = ko.observable().extend({
        'bind': {
            self: self,
            property: "person"
        }
    });

    return self;
};

var a = new Address();
a.street = "Wallstr";

var p = new Person();
p.name = "Sjoerd";

var vm = {
    results: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("root"));

//a.person(p); // Which should make: p.a() == a;
a.person(p);
vm.results.push(p.address() == a);

//a.person(null); // Which should make: p.a() == null;
a.person(null);
vm.results.push(p.address() == null);
```

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd.  I've updated the question with my TS translation of your answer.

Comment: Played a little bit in jsfiddle ^^. Added support for arrays. http://jsfiddle.net/vBrw2/8/

Comment: Nice! Will translate this to TS and post back soon.